# Crop VoronoiMesh by States Latitude and Longitude

Tags: plotting

I want to crop a `VoronoiMesh` output (made with some point inside a Country state) by this same state border.

I downloaded a `.kmz` file [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gec-tools/B4Wc-JQ6QcQ/puVAnEM-YLsJ). From this file, I saved the border of São Paulo state in another `.kmz` file. The command below is how I plotted the state border of São Paulo:

```
spStateForm = {Transparent, Import["SP.kmz", "Data"][[1, 2, 2]]}
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], spStateForm}]`
```

To plot the contour of this specific State.

How to proceed to crop the `VoronoiMesh`? And then, how to output both Images/Graphics (I don't know how to call it) to show the `VoronoiMesh` inside the state, without it's own default border and it's lines conecting to the borders?

What I did above is a acceptable way to begin solving this problem?

Comment: Ignoring lack of contents of `SP.kmz`, a question popped in my mind: how to compute Voronoi diagrams on a geoid, or other non-Euclidean surfaces?